# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error when using typedef struct in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct data
{

    int num;
    struct node *link;
}node;
main()
{
    node *s=NULL,*e=NULL,*new;
    new=malloc(sizeof(node));
    s=malloc(sizeof(node));
    s->num=10;
    s->link=new;
    new->num=8;
    new->link=NULL;
 //  printf("%d\n",s->link->num);  //// error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    e=s;
    while(e!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",e->num);
        e=e->link;
    }

}
```

For the above C program I got the correct output. But if I include the commented line, it generates a dereferencing incomplete type error. Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: I was able to compile and run your code with no warning and errors simply changing `typedef struct data` to `typedef struct node`.

Comment: Basic stuff: you cannot use the `typedef` name inside the struct you're `typedef`'ing. the type is also `node`, not `struct node`. Because you used `struct node`, you're implying there is a `struct node` declared somewhere.

Comment: This code works. But if I include that commented printf statement, it generates error

Comment: try my modifications below, it should work fine.

Comment: That does not make any difference. Please explain me the reason why the code works correctly without that commented line

Comment: @elantra Now I will write the whole code, which does not give any error on my compiler and prints out 8 10 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a naming confusion.

`node` == `struct data` thanks to `typedef`.

But `node` != `struct node`. They are 2 distinct types. And `struct node` has not been defined.

This is a pity that such a confusing construction is allowed by the C standard, and not even flagged as a warning by compilers. But that's the way C is defined today, so we have to live with it.

My recommendation : don't use the same names for `struct` and `typedef`. Create your own convention, for example `struct thing_s` and `typedef struct thing_s thing_t;` . This will avoid naming confusions such as this one.

The solution is now pretty obvious.
Replace :

`typedef struct data { int num; struct node *link; } node;`

by

`typedef struct data { int num; struct data *link; } node;`

and the problematic `printf` will now work.

But your question is : why does your program worked at all without this `printf` ?

Now that's an interesting one.

Let's go back to the initial definition.
As we said, `struct node` doesn't exist, and is therefore incomplete.
Just to better follow what we are going to explain, let's call it `struct incomplete_s` instead. Now, `node` becomes :

`typedef struct data { int num; struct incomplete_s *link; } node;`

It will still work without the problematic `printf`.

The reason is, `node` is properly defined. It is a structure with known size and types. Because it doesn't matter that `struct incomplete_s` is incomplete, since `link` is defined as a pointer to it. You could as well have defined `void * link;` and it would still work.

`void*` or `struct incomplete_s *` or `whatever *` have all same size : they are all pointers. So the structure hosting them can be properly created.

In your main loop, your program does :

```
   while(e!=NULL)
   {
      printf("%d\n",e->num);
      e=e->link;
   }
```

that is `e`, which is a pointer `node*`, takes the value of `e->link`, which is a pointer  `struct incomplete_s *`.

Note that both pointers are supposed to point to different types.
But they are both pointers, so yeah, this assignment is technically possible and authorized by the standard.

Now a more cautious compiler would likely issue a warning here, since you are not supposed to mix pointers of different types. This is a silent type-casting, which is a recipe for future bugs.
I don't know which compiler you use, but you could increase its warning level (use "warning level 4" for Visual, or `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc), and it will likely not like this `=` operation.

A more explicit type casting would solve that (*) :
`e = (node*)(e->link);`

Now this is no more silent, programmer is in charge, warnings will disappear.

`e->link` definitely exists, so compiler can grab this value.
But `s->link->num` doesn't exist, since `s->link` is `struct incomplete_s*`, and we don't know what it is, so we don't know if it has a `num` member.

(*) *Overkill complement* : At some higher optimization level, this will still be not good : [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) might get in the way. So dereferencing a pointer type into another pointer type remains a dangerous operation.

Comment: Great! This a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should modify your struct, and the error of the commented part should be solved:

```
typedef struct data
{

   int num;
   struct data *link;

}node;
```

When you are defining s and new in the following lines, there is no need to put them equal to NULL, This is the working fine main function:

```
void main(){
   node *s,*e,*new;
   e=NULL;

   new=malloc(sizeof(node));
   s=malloc(sizeof(node));
   s->num=10;
   new->num=8;
   new->link=NULL;
   s->link=new;
   printf("%d\n",s->link->num);  /// works fine without any error
   e=s;
   while(e!=NULL)
   {
      printf("%d\n",e->num);
      e=e->link;
   }
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`struct node` is undeclared in this code, so `struct node*` is an incomplete type.

I guess `struct node *link;` in the declaration of struct should be `struct data *link;`.

Comment: what about this; `s->link=new;
    new->num=8;
    new->link=NULL;`

Comment: But I am getting the output if the printf("%d\n",s->link->num); is commented.Can you please help me with the reason?  s->link->num creates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer is: you defined a type that needs one structure that is not being declared.

The reasons you are getting the error on the commented line is because it's the unique line you used a member of the link member in the node structure. On any other part of your code you don't hit it as you do, for example, `e = new->link;` the compiler don't need to know about the members of the structure at this time because you said that `e` is of type node, node is a structure  and `new->link` is a compatible structure, so everything is ok.

That's also the reason when you change the `typedef struct data { …};` to `typedef struct node { …};` and everything works, because when the compiler needs the information about the structure node it finds a structure called node and there is a member called link that have a member called num. As you can see, typedef is just a kind of aliasing. Hope it helps you to understand.