# Linked list using C for insertion of a node at nth position

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, declaration, singly-linked-list

I have written this code using C and i am a new to programming world so please help me regarding my error. I am getting dereferencing pointer to incomplete type. what are the changes I need to make to run this code?

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct {
int data;
struct node* next;
};
struct node* head;

void Insert(int data, int n)
{
int i;
struct node* temp1, *temp2;
temp1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp1->data = data;
temp1->next = NULL;
if(n==1)
    {
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }

 temp2 = head;
  for(i=0; i<n-2; i++)
  {
      temp2 = temp2->next;
  }
  temp1->next = temp2->next;
  temp2->next = temp1;

}

void print()
{
struct node* temp = head;
while(temp != NULL)
{
    printf("%d", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
}
print("\n");
}

int main()
{
head = NULL;
Insert(2,1);
Insert(3,2);
Insert(4,1);
Insert(5,2);
Insert(1,3);
Print();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error when using typedef struct in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607042/dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type-error-when-using-typedef-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You omitted tag name node in the structure definition

```
struct {
int data;
struct node* next;
};
```

Write instead

```
struct node {
       ^^^^ 
int data;
struct node* next;
};
```

Take into account that by the analogy with arrays it is better when positions in the list start from 0.

Also function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

and function print should be declared like

```
void print( void );
```

Comment: thanxx mate.. it worked..